# How to use JSF's h:selectBooleanCheckbox with h:dataTable to get selected checkboxes without submitting the page content?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In my application, I have a h:datatable which contains vehicles data and h:selectBooleanCheckBox in each of its row. I want know the selected checkbox in the datatable datatable's row in the backing bean without applying any submit button. The idea of doing this is; when any user clicks the check boxes in one application page, s/he could easily see the selected rows in other pages aswell beacause the datatable in every page contains many vehicles. Therefore, users could be able to see the selected vehicles in any page and do the related operation.

The following shows part of my JSF page.

```
<rich:dataTable id="vehicleTable" var="vhcl" value="#{mainPage.vehicleList}"
binding="#{mainPage.vehicleTable}" > 
<rich:column id="col_sel" width="10px"
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="#{general.showOnMap}" onclick="showOnMap(this)"   id="selectedCheckBox" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="trackId" label="#{general.vehicleName}" >
    <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="#{general.vehicleName}" id="state_name" />
    </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{vhcl.vehicle.mtsTrackId}" id="vehicleId" title="#{general.vehicleId}" style="font-size:10px; color:blue;" />
    <br/>
<h:outputText value="#{vhcl.vehicle.vehiclePlate}" id="vehiclePlate" title="#{general.licencePlate}" style="font-size:10px; color:blue"/>
</rich:column>
<rich:column  id="type_col" label="#{general.vehicleType}" >
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{general.vehichleType}" id="vehichleTypeLabel" />
</f:facet>
<h:graphicImage value="#{vhcl.typeImage}" height="40" width="40" align="left"/>
<h:panelGrid columns="1" align="right">
    <h:graphicImage id="statusImage" value="#{vhcl.statusImage}" title="#{vhcl.status}" height="15" width="15" />
    <h:graphicImage id="motorStatusImage" value="#{vhcl.motorStatusImage}" title="#{vhcl.motorStatus}" height="15" width="15" />
</h:panelGrid>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="msg_col" label="#{general.lastMessageDate}" >
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{general.lastMessageDate}" id="lastMsgDateLabel" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{vhcl.messageDate}" id="lastMsgDate" /> 
<br />
<h:outputText value="Hız: " />
<h:outputText value="#{vhcl.instantSpeed}" id="lastSpeed" style="color:blue; font-weight:bold" />
<h:outputText value="km/s" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="addr_col" label="#{general.address}" >
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{general.address}" id="addressLabel"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{vhcl.address}" id="addr" />
<br />
<h:outputText value="#{vhcl.location}" id="location" style="color:blue;" />
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Vehicle` class create a `Boolean` field and add `getter` and `setter` methods for it like this.

```
private Boolean selected;

public Boolean getSelected() {
  return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
  this.selected = selected;
}
```

Then bind your `checkBox` to that property and add a `<a4j:support>` tag to the `checkBox` as below.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="showOnMap(this)" value="#{vhcl.selected}">
  <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox
```

Now when you check or uncheck the `checkBox` the value is submitted to the bean. Then any time you can find whether the `vehicle` is selected like this.

```
if(vehicle.selected != null && vehicle.selected) {
  //vehicle is selected
}
```

Note: Your table should be inside a form.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. It made my code much stable. However, it didn't solve my actual problem. The point is I have a menu bar which contains a main page and a report page. both main page and report pages contains the same vehicles table. When a user for example enters the main page and selects some vehicles to see on the map, s/he could also see the same checked vehicles in the report page as well. So far, I can see selected vehicles by submitting the form in mainpage by a button. Is it possible to put the selected vehicles to JSF session from within Javascript code w/out form submission?

Comment: Something here is not clear for me. Are you going to keep both pages opened in different tabs at the same time? Or when you select the second page from the menu does the second page load in current tab? For second option your bean should be session scoped and if you are using `<a4j:support>`s, selections of first page will be reflected in second page.

Comment: When I select the second page, it is loaded in the same tab. My bean is session scoped of course but when I select some vehicles in the first page I have to submit it to the form via a button or a link. I don't want to put a button or something in the page. When I select the vehicles in the first page with <a4j:support> I cannot see them on the second page without submitting to the first page form. I thought something like when I select the vehicles in the first page, I should keep them in the backing bean via Javascript code not with a submition button then get them in the second page.

Comment: If your table is wrapped with a `form` and your `checkBoxe`s include `<a4j:support>`s the value of the `checkBox` is submitted when you changed any check box. Actually I am unable to find where is the problem. :(

Comment: Yes, it's wrapped with a form however I am now able to select just one vehicle from the check boxes in every row of the table even if I select many of them.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions to my work. Actually I was able to select many check box in a different way like              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="#{general.showOnMap}" value="#{mainPage.checked[vhcl.id]}"
             onclick="showOnMap(this)" id="selectedCheckBox" >
             <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>. checked[vhcl.vehicle.mtsTrackId] is a hashMap and it keeps the related vehicels id.